# what exactly means this struct definition?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

sorry for this newbie question but I don't find any good resource on web to explain what this means:

```
struct {
  struct spinlock lock;
  struct proc proc[NPROC]; //NPROC = 64
} ptable;
```

I see the resources over the web and find these types of define a struct:

```
//first method
struct Foo { ... };

//second method
typedef struct Foo { ... } Foo;
```

Comment: [Good Books List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct foo { ... };
```

The struct tag (`foo` here) is optional. If it's omitted like in your example, you can use the variable `ptable` which is  of this type, but you can't define other variables of this type later.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct 
{
  struct spinlock lock;
  struct proc proc[NPROC]; //NPROC = 64
}
ptable;
```

This defines a [nameless `struct`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626597/what-might-you-use-a-nameless-struct-or-union-for) and at the same time declares a variable named `ptable`

As pointed by Yu Hao, you can't define variables of this struct type later. You can make as many variables  at the time you define the nameless struct

```
struct 
{
   /* your variables*/
} a,b[2] ;
```

as opposed to a named struct,

```
struct my_struct
{
   /* your variables*/
} a,b[2] ;
```

and you can define variables later as `struct my_struct c`